# Необычный метод get в php

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, есть такой вопрос: как передавать в гет не сколько значений?
Например, есть ссылка

> http://www.dostavka.ru/request/ProductComparePageRequest?**product_id=6490057-6553652-6582008**

В конце в значения **`product_id`** идут несколько айдишников, ну и обрабатывают их по-своему. Сам вопрос: как правильно принять такое значение и дальше работать с этими айдишниками?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть два принципиально разных пути.

1. script.php?product_id=6490057-6553652-6582008

тогда

```
$produnct_ids = explode('-',$_GET['product_id']);  
//$produnct_ids[1] ==  6553652;
```

1. script.php?product_id[]=6490057&product_id[]=6553652&product_id[]=6582008;

тогда

```
$produnct_ids = $_GET['product_id'];  
//$produnct_ids[1] ==  6553652;
```

Второй способ предпочтительнее. Реализация на стороне клиента:

```
<input type="text" name="produnct_id[]" value="6490057" /><br />
<input type="text" name="produnct_id[]" value="6553652" /><br />
<input type="text" name="produnct_id[]" value="6582008" /><br />
```

Обратите внимание на скобки!!!

**UPD**
Получаемые массивы $product_ids идентичны. Через эхо его можно вывести так:

```
echo '<pre>'.print_r($product_ids,true).'</pre>';
```

или так:

```
echo implode(',',$product_ids);
```

или так:

```
foreach($product_ids as $id){
  print($id.'<br />');
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, последний вопрос прям вот детский, по первому методу, мы получаем массив, и как весь его вывести через echo ?тоесть все 3 значения, в цикле

Comment: см. Апдейт

Answer (score 1):

А чего сложного то ?:))) 
Я бы так делал:

http://www.dostavka.ru/request/ProductComparePageRequest?product_id=6490057,6553652,6582008

На стороне сервера:

```
if($_GET[product_id])
      $array_id = split(',',$_GET[product_id]); //Из полученной строки сплитим значения по запятой.
```

Далее, у нас есть массив с айдишниками.
и делаем с ними все, что угодно.